# 404 error after deployment of Symfony 6 API

Tags: symfony, deployment, http-status-code-404, router

I am currently developing an API using symfony 6 (I am new to this technology). Everything works fine in local environment. However, I tried deploying my API (on my website poly-api.fr) and I get 404 errors for every routes.

For the deployment I followed the steps of the symfony documentation :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html

I also made sure the permissions were set correctly.

In the end, I was able to migrate my database, and to visualize the routes on available using the command:

```
php bin/console debug:router
```

[image: Output of the command]

Here is an example of a 404 I get:

When I try to access **poly-api.fr/get/stats** I get this 404 error :

[image: 404 error]

Here are the logs corresponding to the execution of this request (it looks like the route called is already not the good one...) :

[image: Logs]

And here are the content of my main files :

**routes.yaml**

```
get_stats:
  path: /get/stats
  controller: App\Controller\StatController::getStats
```

**.env**

[image: .env file]

```
**StatController.php**

class StatController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/get/stats/", name="get_stats", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function getStats(CarTHRepository $carRepo, BrandRepository $brandRepo, CarTypeRepository $carTypeRepo): JsonResponse
    {
        $cars = $carRepo->findAll();
        $brands = $brandRepo->findAll();
        $types = $carTypeRepo->findAll();

        if ($cars == null || $brands == null || $types == null) {
            return $this->json([
                'response' => 'notFound'
            ]);
        }       

        return new JsonResponse([
            'response' => 'ok',
            'result' => [
                'cars' => count($cars),
                'brands' => count($brands),
                'types' => count($types)
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

.htaccess (generated by my hosting platform)

```
######### Generated by Lwspanel #########
######### Ne pas modifier / Don't touch #########

# Redirections https poly-api.fr
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?poly-api\.fr(?:.*)$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [redirect=301,L]

######### End Generated by Lwspanel #########
```

Comment: Upon first look it seems like your host is pointing to one directory higher than your actual symphony app. You need to see how to configure your web host to point to the /public folder. RIght now I can see your vendor and var directories, which I should not be able to.